# Geoserver WMS limiting map visibility by scale

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoserver, wms, scale, zoom

In ArcGIS I can manually limit visibility of a map layer by specifying a min and max scale (see below).

[image]

Is it possible to instead set this server-side on Geoserver? I've seen something similar in Tile Caching but didn't see it enforced when i tested it in ArcGIS.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In GeoServer scale dependencies are expressed inside the styles, see:
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/rules.html

Comment: So if SLD or SLD_BODY is enabled for a service, a scale range could be overridden for a layer

Comment: You can disable that, search for "dynamic styling" in the WMS configuration, also check GeoFence ability to control styles on a layer by layer basis.

Comment: Yes, but if it's enabled because you have some layers you want to be dynamically styled, it's an issue to be aware of.

Comment: You can put them in a separate workspace for example.

Comment: but you can't fix the scale (range) and have dynamic styling on the same layer, as you can with ArcGIS and MapServer.

Comment: True. The project welcomes contributions, anyone in need of such functionality can contribute it. So far we haven't had a paid project sponsoring it, but tomorrow that might change, finger crossed :-D